# Asyc Task return Arraylist retrieve it?

Tags: android

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(myPrefs.getString("IP", ""), null, null);
```

I returns an Arraylist  from the dobackground method..how to put it into my arraylist?

```
Arraylist al=null;

al=new DownloadFilesTask().execute(myPrefs.getString("IP", ""), null, null);
```

not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I returns an Arraylist from the dobackground method..how to put it into my arraylist?

By assigning your local `ArrayList` from the `doInBackground()` method to your global `ArrayList` before returning it.

Sample code:

```
@Override
protected ArrayList doInBackground(...) {
     ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList();
     // Other stuff you might have.
     // ...
     return mYourGlobalArrayList = localArrayList;
}
```

Comment: bt this Asyc class is not inside my class?

Comment: @Harinder: I never got that information, but when you are constructing your `AsyncTask`, pass a reference from your `Activity`'s object instance to a member field of your `AsyncTask` class and create a callback method in your `Activity` which has an `ArrayList` as a parameter and make that method assign the `ArrayList` to your `Activity`'s global `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this in ur code

```
//After Preexecute...


@Override
                protected ArrayList doInBackground(...) {
                     ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList();
                     // Other stuff you might have.
                     // ...
                     return localArrayList;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(result!= null)
                    {
                        ArrayList<String> category = new ArrayList<String>();
                        category = (ArrayList<String>) result;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Then You can assign this arraylist to your arraylist in post execute

Answer (score 0):

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>>() {

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
                //result = do some work
                            ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList();
                         //   localArrayList = get from your website or from database
                          // assign arraylist globally
                return result;
            }


        }.execute("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Return it from your doInBackground method, and bind that in onPostExecute method.

In onPostExecute method, you can get return value of doInBackground as parameter value